# ExtJS Grid Panel not populating data from store

Tags: javascript, extjs

Does anyone see what's wrong with this code?  I'm following an example from ExtJS in action.  The grid panel is being displayed but the data is not being populated.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

        var arrayData = [
            ['Jay Garcia', 'MD'],
            ['Aaron Baker', 'VA'],
            ['Susan Smith', 'DC'],
            ['Mary Stein', 'DE'],
            ['Bryan Shanley', 'NJ'],
            ['Nyri Selgado', 'CA']
        ];

        var nameRecord = Ext.data.Record.create([
            { name : 'name', mapping : 1 },
            { name : 'state', mapping : 2 }
        ]);

        var arrayReader = new Ext.data.ArrayReader({}, nameRecord);

        var memoryProxy = new Ext.data.MemoryProxy(arrayData);

        var store = new Ext.data.Store({
            reader : arrayReader,
            proxy : memoryProxy
        });

        var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
            {
                header : 'Full Name',
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex : 'name'
            },
            {
                header : 'State',
                dataIndex : 'state'
            }
        ]);

        var gridView = new Ext.grid.GridView();

        var selModel = new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
            singleSelect : true
        });

        var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            title : 'My First Grid',
            renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
            autoHeight : true,
            width : 250,
            store : store,
            view : gridView,
            colModel : colModel,
            selModel : selModel
        });

});
```

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you using?

Comment: If you are starting new project I would recommend to use most recent version 4+

Comment: Not starting a new project, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The author forgot to include autoLoad : true in the data store.