# ExtJS 6 Grid Panel Store does not populate

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, gridpanel

I've read through post by post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386623/extjs-grid-panel-not-populating-data-from-store), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572954/extjs-json-store-not-populating), [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312320/ext-grid-panel-not-loading-data-from-ext-data-store), [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150304/extjs-ajax-call-store-not-loading#), but nothing's work in my problem. So I would like to raise my question here: How to populate ExtJS grid panel with PHP (I'm using ExtJS 6.2)?

```
var programStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    remoteSort: false,
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/navigasipskl/model/izin.php',
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST',
            update: 'POST',
            create: 'POST'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'root',
            idProperty: 'id'
        }
    },
    sorters: [{
       property: 'id',
       direction: 'ASC'
    }],
    fields: [
        {name: 'id'},
        {name: 'provinsi'},
        {name: 'kabkot'},
        {name: 'kecamatan'},
        {name: 'desa'},
        {name: 'skema'},
        {name: 'hl'},
        {name: 'hp'},
        {name: 'hpt'},
        {name: 'hpk'},
        {name: 'sk_no'},
        {name: 'sk_tanggal'},
        {name: 'sk_luas'},
        {name: 'lembaga_jenis'},
        {name: 'lembaga_nama'},
        {name: 'pendamping_lembaga'},
        {name: 'pendamping_nama'},
        {name: 'pendamping_kontak'},
        {name: 'pendamping_email'},
        {name: 'komoditi_jenis'},
        {name: 'komoditi_nama'},
        {name: 'komoditi_luas'},
        {name: 'jml_kk'},
        {name: 'ketua_nama'},
        {name: 'ketua_kontak'},
        {name: 'ketua_email'},
        {name: 'factsheet'},
        {name: 'file_sk'},
        {name: 'file_peta'},
        {name: 'p_83'},
        {name: 'pemegang_izin'},
        {name: 'jenis_izin_pemanfaatan'},
        {name: 'kelompok_mitra'},
        {name: 'jenis_kemitraan'}
    ]
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('programStore'),
    columns: [
        {text: 'Id', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'id', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Provinsi', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'provinsi'},
        {text: 'Kabupaten/Kota', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'kabkot', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Kecamatan', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'kecamatan', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Desa', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'desa', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Skema', flex: 2, dataIndex: 'skema'},
        {text: 'Hutan Lindung', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'hl', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Hutan Produksi', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'hp', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Hutan Produksi Terbatas', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'hpt', hidden: true},
        {text: 'HPK', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'hpk', hidden: true},
        {text: 'SK No', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'sk_no', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Jenis Lembaga', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'lembaga_jenis', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Nama Lembaga', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'lembaga_nama', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Nama Komoditi', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'komoditi_nama'},
        {text: 'Jumlah KK', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'jml_kk'},
        {text: 'Nama Ketua', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'ketua_nama'},
        {text: 'Kontak Ketua', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'ketua_kontak', hidden:true},
        {text: 'Izin Pemanfaatan', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'jenis_izin_pemanfaatan', hidden:true},
        {text: 'Jenis Kemitraan', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'jenis_kemitraan', hidden:true}
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

And here is my query results:
`[
    {
        id: "1",
        provinsi: "SUMATERA UTARA",
        kabkot: "TAPANULI SELATAN",
        kecamatan: "Sayur Matinggi",
        desa: "Aek Badak Julu",
        skema: "HD",
        hl: "435",
        hp: "0",
        hpt: null,
        hpk: "0",
        sk_no: "SK.1010/Menlhk-PSKL/PKPS/PSL.0/3/2017",
        sk_tanggal: "3/10/2017",
        sk_luas: "435",
        lembaga_jenis: null,
        lembaga_nama: null,
        pendamping_lembaga: null,
        pendamping_nama: null,
        pendamping_kontak: null,
        pendamping_email: null,
        komoditi_jenis: null,
        komoditi_nama: null,
        komoditi_luas: "0",
        jml_kk: "348",
        ketua_nama: "Kasnihati / -",
        ketua_kontak: "082165489955 / -",
        ketua_email: null,
        factsheet: null,
        file_sk: null,
        file_peta: null,
        p_83: "sesudah",
        pemegang_izin: null,
        jenis_izin_pemanfaatan: null,
        kelompok_mitra: null,
        jenis_kemitraan: null
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        provinsi: "SUMATERA UTARA",
        kabkot: "TAPANULI TENGAH",
        kecamatan: "Andam",
        desa: "Sigolang",
        skema: "HD",
        hl: "0",
        hp: "1414",
        hpt: null,
        hpk: "0",
        sk_no: "SK.1014/Menlhk-PSKL/PKPS/PSL.0/3/2017",
        sk_tanggal: "3/10/2017",
        sk_luas: "1414",
        lembaga_jenis: null,
        lembaga_nama: null,
        pendamping_lembaga: null,
        pendamping_nama: null,
        pendamping_kontak: null,
        pendamping_email: null,
        komoditi_jenis: null,
        komoditi_nama: null,
        komoditi_luas: "0",
        jml_kk: "170",
        ketua_nama: "Jarifon Tinam Bunan / -",
        ketua_kontak: "081375194193 / -",
        ketua_email: null,
        factsheet: null,
        file_sk: "SK HPHD SIGOLANG.pdf",
        file_peta: "SIGOLANG.JPG",
        p_83: "sesudah",
        pemegang_izin: null,
        jenis_izin_pemanfaatan: null,
        kelompok_mitra: null,
        jenis_kemitraan: null
    }
]`

Please anyone help me. Any thought is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what does not work and are you sure that "/navigasipskl/model/izin.php" is available?

Comment: I've checked through network browser and I can get the data routed with "localhost/navigasipskl/model.izin.php". The root problem I think that I could not populate the data to my grid panel :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the store into the variable. [StoreManager](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.StoreManager.html) is expecting the store to have storeId also I think it expects the store to be defined using Ext.define

If you create the store into a variable as you did you can than pass the variable into the store config directly. No need to use store manager.

```
var programStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    remoteSort: false,
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/navigasipskl/model/izin.php',
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST',
            update: 'POST',
            create: 'POST'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'root',
            idProperty: 'id'
        }
    },
    sorters: [{
       property: 'id',
       direction: 'ASC'
    }],
    fields: [
        {name: 'id'},
        {name: 'provinsi'},
        {name: 'kabkot'},
        {name: 'kecamatan'},
        {name: 'desa'},
        {name: 'skema'},
        {name: 'hl'},
        {name: 'hp'},
        {name: 'hpt'},
        {name: 'hpk'},
        {name: 'sk_no'},
        {name: 'sk_tanggal'},
        {name: 'sk_luas'},
        {name: 'lembaga_jenis'},
        {name: 'lembaga_nama'},
        {name: 'pendamping_lembaga'},
        {name: 'pendamping_nama'},
        {name: 'pendamping_kontak'},
        {name: 'pendamping_email'},
        {name: 'komoditi_jenis'},
        {name: 'komoditi_nama'},
        {name: 'komoditi_luas'},
        {name: 'jml_kk'},
        {name: 'ketua_nama'},
        {name: 'ketua_kontak'},
        {name: 'ketua_email'},
        {name: 'factsheet'},
        {name: 'file_sk'},
        {name: 'file_peta'},
        {name: 'p_83'},
        {name: 'pemegang_izin'},
        {name: 'jenis_izin_pemanfaatan'},
        {name: 'kelompok_mitra'},
        {name: 'jenis_kemitraan'}
    ]
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: programStore, // use variable if not using Ext.define
    columns: [
        {text: 'Id', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'id', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Provinsi', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'provinsi'},
        {text: 'Kabupaten/Kota', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'kabkot', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Kecamatan', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'kecamatan', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Desa', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'desa', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Skema', flex: 2, dataIndex: 'skema'},
        {text: 'Hutan Lindung', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'hl', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Hutan Produksi', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'hp', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Hutan Produksi Terbatas', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'hpt', hidden: true},
        {text: 'HPK', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'hpk', hidden: true},
        {text: 'SK No', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'sk_no', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Jenis Lembaga', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'lembaga_jenis', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Nama Lembaga', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'lembaga_nama', hidden: true},
        {text: 'Nama Komoditi', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'komoditi_nama'},
        {text: 'Jumlah KK', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'jml_kk'},
        {text: 'Nama Ketua', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'ketua_nama'},
        {text: 'Kontak Ketua', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'ketua_kontak', hidden:true},
        {text: 'Izin Pemanfaatan', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'jenis_izin_pemanfaatan', hidden:true},
        {text: 'Jenis Kemitraan', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'jenis_kemitraan', hidden:true}
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Btw if you are just using this grid in your app as extra component it might be fine but if you are building pure ExtJS app I think you should rather use Ext.define, define your classes and use more "standard" approach to creating stores / grids / classes in general

You can check many ExtJS examples in the kitchen-sink http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#array-grid

Comment: Oh I missed to put the storeId param in my store variable!! Now, i can populate it to my grid panel with specify store by: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('programStore') in grid panel. Thank you for your help @pagep !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a storeId for the store to use with StoreManager
[extjs 6 StoreManager documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.StoreManager.html)